# Start Activity in Lock Screen on Marshmallow or Higher devices

Tags: android, sinch

I'm creating a calling app with sinch service. 
For Incoming calls, I need to unlock the lockscreen programatically. Using flags I solved this, but its not working on Nougat.

my current code in activity:

```
  @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);    }
```

and on manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="IncomingCallScreenActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">          
</activity>
```

**Update:**

Problem is solved. I edited in the manifest:

```
<activity
android:name="IncomingCallScreenActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: did you add permissions?

Comment: yes i added permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also used  sinch service.  For Incoming call, i solved  this problem .I hope your problem can be solved by trying this:

1.Replace

```
 <activity
   android:name="IncomingCallScreenActivity"
   android:noHistory="true"
   android:showOnLockScreen="true"
   android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">         
</activity>
```

By

```
<activity 
   android:name="IncomingCallScreenActivity"> 
</activity>
```

2.Code on onCreate() in your activity:

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);    }
```

Comment: in oneplus device this solutions is not worked can you please help me?

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan have you found a the solution?

Answer (score 0):

From Android O and above, if your application is in the background, your application is allowed to create and run background services for some minutes, afterwards your application will enter in the idle stage, and all background service will be stopped.

Posible solution is to use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) api introduced in API21 to perform background tasks.

Comment: I am not facing any problem of background task. cause call is coming from the service.  I just want to disable keyguard of phone lock when call is coming.

Comment: I think you should use  getWindow()...block before calling Activities onCreate  method

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use getWindow()...block before calling Activities onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);    
super.onCreate();
}
```

You should add permissions in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Comment: yes i added those permissions. and worked for lower devices. but not in nougat. However I got the solution from  @md minhajul islam